# Problematic using Captcha on billing page

Tags: validation, captcha, security

I have simple captcha on user page. I want make it refresh if user input incorrect captcha, I just wanna ask Should I do it or I just add a simple button to refresh it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In terms of making the user experience pleasant, you should do both:

- manual refresh button in case the CAPTCHA image that the user receives is unclear to the user
- automatic refresh if they attempt to authenticate themselves and enter the incorrect response

Comment: @Shaun- i want implement automatic refresh when user input incorrect captcha.. it's right isn't ?